# Div structure. Error displaying images

Tags: jquery, css, html

I am working on a little website.

I've just loaded the index into the website to show you "graphical" problem with Firefox and IE.

The adress is http://www.anticamaddalena.it

The problem is this:

Safari is displaying the page fine. Everything works correctly. The images of the "sections" are fine and correctly attached.

Firefox and IE aren't displaying correctly the div structure with its related image "cascade".
I mean, I see a space between the "buttons". The image are not attached, it's not fluid.

I've tried on the css with 0 margins, border 0 on the img tag, and 0 padding on the css.

I'm not an experienced programmer, just a newbie that's learning. What could cause that kind of problem?

Here the are 2 img links showing the problem:

SAFARI:
[image]

FIREFOX:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

add css property

```
display: inline-block;
```

to your 'a' elements used with those images.

Comment: Seems to solve it for firefox. Any idea why this happens or just trial and error?

Comment: What means "messes everything"?
What was the css rule you apply?

Comment: to the divs that contain images and <a href links

Comment: @user1821530
I tested applying the rule:
#blocco_centrale a,
    #blocco_centrale a:visited {
     display: inline-block;
    }

Comment: As I said:
apply to 'a' elements. not to the divs

Comment: @FabrícioMatté
I test inline-block and it worked, just that.
The tag 'a' is an inline element, so sometimes may not work right, and also the HTML didn't have the height and width of the img tag set.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding

```
#blocco_centrale div a {
  line-height: 0px;
}
```

or

```
#blocco_centrale div a {
  display: block;
}
```

in to your stylesheet. It will fix the issue. But I recommend you to use a better HTML structure and CSS.